# Check if UITextField is empty or not on viewDidLoad and enable button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I have mutiple UItextFields in a ViewController. Also I have outlet functions from storyboard to check if the textfields are empty or not and I am enabling a button only when the textfields are non-empty.

For a few of the textfields I am setting the data before viewDidLoad so the user does not have to manually enter it. Even though these textfields have data, they have to be clicked once so that button gets enabled.

```
var isFirstNameValid = false
@IBAction func validateFirstName(sender: AnyObject) {
        guard (!firstNameText.text!.isEmpty) else{
            isFirstNameValid = false
            return
        }
        isFirstNameValid = true
        enableRegisterButton()
    }


func enableRegisterButton()
    {
        guard (isFirstNameValid) else{
            registerButton.enabled = false
            return
        }
        registerButton.enabled = true
    }
```

I want to enable the button when the textfield has data entered by the user or programatically set before viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Where does the data come from that fills the text fields when the user loads the view controller ?

Comment: I have a struct that stores the coreLocation data that I'm trying to fill in the textfield for address.

Comment: Why not just put the code that checks for filled-in text fields inside viewDidLoad and enable the buttons right there

Comment: I want to validate a few textfields on the fly for e.g if the user has entered correct email ID

Comment: So, what exactly isn't working? Enabling the button all the time or only when the text field is pre-filled without user intervention?

Comment: Enabling the button when the textfield is pre-filled is not working

Comment: See my answer for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation code needs to run without user interaction and the best place to do this is in `viewDidLoad`. Create a checker function which takes in a UITextField as its argument and does the actual checking. This way, you can call that checker function in `viewDidLoad` as well as later on when you validate actual user input in your IBAction or wherever.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This is where your code to set firstNameText goes

    let isFirstNameValid = checker(firstNameText)

    myButton.enabled = false
    if isFirstNameValid { registerButton.enabled = true }
}

func checker(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    guard (!textField.text!.isEmpty) else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

---

**Side Note**

The `enableRegisterButton()` function is extraneous. You've already done the checking which is what called the function to begin with, so checking if the first name is valid inside the `enableRegisterButton` is redundant. The only useful line in that function is `registerButton.enabled = true`, which we can write without using the function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems be good, but i think you need to try to replace this:

```
@IBAction func validateFirstName(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard (!firstNameText.text!.isEmpty) else{
        isFirstNameValid = false
        return
    }
    isFirstNameValid = true
    enableRegisterButton()
}
```

**by**

```
@IBAction func validateFirstName(sender: AnyObject) {
    isFirstNameValid = !firstNameText.text!.isEmpty
    enableRegisterButton()
}
```

**OR:**

You can check in your connections inspector for a `Value Changed` event and add the method.

Even if it's not working, you can check for your data value in the `viewWillAppear()` method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    registerButton.enabled = !firstNameText.text!.isEmpty
}
```

Comment: Even after adding value changed event the button does not get enabled. However if I click the textfield once the button gets enabled. I want the button to be enabled when the textfield value is already set and the user is able to see data in the text field

Comment: Also you can check the text in your textfield with breakpoint in the `viewWillAppear()` method . But, you just want to enabled a button when there is a text inside a textfield ? That's right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But as you say "when the textfield has data entered by the user" so you can't do it before viewDidLoad.I think you should explain more.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

and

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    //your code.enable your button here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate all the the textfields once in viewDidLoad() and try to enable register button. This way register button will be enabled even if all of the textfields are pre-filled without requiring you to click any of them
Like this:

```
isFirstNameValid = !firstNameText.text!.isEmpty
isLastNameValid = !lastNameText.text!.isEmpty
// rest of the fileds...
enableRegisterButton()
```